# Running python as service in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, python, services, datascience-anaconda

I am currently trying to run python as a service in ubuntu. I am running into an error when trying to run it as a service.
This is what my service looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=PythonAPI

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/User/path/anaconda3/envs/envs-name/bin/python3 /path/to/executable


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I try to run the service I get this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hosting'.

If I just run the ExecStart in the command line it seems to run no problem. Any reason why it wouldn't work in a service?

Comment: You need to enable the environment. So that specific python3 binary knows where to look for modules.

Comment: I have the environment enabled on the server. It shows it on the left side of my ubuntu cli. As I said it runs when i just run it as a cli command. It just wont run when running it as a service.

Comment: Your shell runs its own environment. Services start their own environment. Since I'm not sure how to set/enable a specific anaconda environment ind a service, I would suggest to put everything (settin/activating the environment ans starting of the scriipt) in a wrapper script and run the wrapper as a service.